# Is DeepStream SDK support Jetson Nano?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, nvidia-deepstream

My goal is to run DeepStream SDK 6.2 (or older version).

The official [SD Card Image](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/learn/get-started-jetson-nano-devkit#write:%7E:text=Jetson%20Nano%20Developer%20Kit%20SD%20Card%20Image) is JP461 (I assume it's JetPack 4.6.1). However, DeepStream SDK 6.2 require JetPack 5.1.

The problem is JetPack 5.1 does not mention Nano at all and I can't find older version of DeepStream SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to see the archived versions of Deepstream without signing in.
You can find the download links [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/deepstream-on-jetson-downloads-archived)

Note that 6.0.1 is the last release for Jetson Nano.
Incase you need docker images, you can directly docker pull on the Jetson (assuming you have Jetpack 4.6.1 installed)

```
docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/deepstream-l4t:6.0.1-base
```

(You can find all the images [here](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/deepstream-l4t/tags))

Comment: I installed it without Docker from [Archived page](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/deepstream-on-jetson-downloads-archived). And by following the [6.0.1 documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/6.0/dev-guide/text/DS_Quickstart.html#install-the-deepstream-sdk)